# Access NAS through internet

Tags: nas, remote-access

I am trying to setup an access to my NAS from internet, however it seems that Ive missed some steps.

- I've made port forwarding on my router (port3669,  80, 21, 9090, 21) to my Nas IP 192.168.0.xx
- I have setup a free account from noIP.com to have an free domain.

but when i access this domain it seems that my router just wont forward to the above specified NAS.... instead Ive got an administration page of a router. Also when I enter e.g. domain.com:3669 I am getting error of problematic communication with the specified page.

Comment: How do you connect to the NAS? You've set port 21 (FTP); but if you use different protocols you need to set port forwarding for the respective ports. E.g. for SMB/samba ports 445 (TCP) or 137-139 (TCP or UDP).

Comment: Hi, i have ny NAS connected to my router via ethernet cable. Next I've configured an http (80) port to be forwarded to my Nas IP 192.168.0.xx, but somehow it is not forwarded. Instead I've got landed to router config page.

Comment: Because you mention port 80 I assume that you are using the NAS as web server. There is already something (config page) running on port 80 of the router, that's why you can't forward that port. You can either change the router config page port (some routers allow you to disable http for the config page and only use https which is on different port) or use different port on the router (e.g. 88 or 8080) to forward to port 80 on the NAS for web services.

Comment: Hi, this is my first time NAS setup so excuse me for my ignorance. Currently I am not using my NAS for anything I am just trying to make an access to it through web for better management. the problem is that my router for some reason wont forward to my NAS. also I am not sue if it helps but when I remove any port forwarding on my router I can still get the router config page when navigate to my domain... Strange ist it?